# using observeEvent for numericInput in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, numeric-input, shinyalert

I have a simple shiny app which I would like to show a warning if user input is bigger than a threshold.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyalert)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("obs", "Observations:", 1),
  verbatimTextOutput("value")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$obs,{
    if(!is.na(input$obs) && input$obs >10){
      shinyalert("warning!", "input too big", type = "warning")
    }
  })
  output$value <- renderText({ input$obs })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

if user is not quick enough to provide input, let say for the `input$obs = 110` we have 1 second delay between putting the second and third value the popups warning will appear !
How should I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `shinyCatch` from `spsComps` to make your life easier

```r
library(shiny)
library(spsComps)
ui <- fluidPage(
    numericInput("obs", "Observations:", 1),
    verbatimTextOutput("value")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$value <- renderText({ 
        shinyCatch({
            if(!is.na(input$obs) && input$obs >10) warning("input too big")
        }, blocking_level = "warning", prefix = "")
        
        input$obs 
    })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

when `blocking_level = "warning"` is specified `shinyCatch` blocks following code in the `renderText` expression. So when your number is larger than 10, the new `input$obs` will not be rendered.

Here's what users see

[image]

Here's what developers see in the console
[image]

Comment: @Iz100, Thanks for the reply, but I just want the warning popup, meaning I want the output to be shown even if the input is bigger than 10.

Comment: @user9112767 Then remove `blocking_level = "warning"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `showNotification()` from shiny itself:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("obs", "Observations:", 1),
  verbatimTextOutput("value")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$obs,{
    if(!is.na(input$obs) && input$obs >10){
      showNotification(
        ui = tags$h4("Input Too Big!"), 
        type = "warning"
      )
    }
  })
  output$value <- renderText({ input$obs })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Or `{shinytoastr}`:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinytoastr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinytoastr::useToastr(), 
  
  numericInput("obs", "Observations:", 1),
  verbatimTextOutput("value")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$obs,{
    if(!is.na(input$obs) && input$obs >10){
      shinytoastr::toastr_warning(
        message = "Decrease it.", 
        title = "Input too big!"
      )
    }
  })
  output$value <- renderText({ input$obs })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Or `{spsComps}` as @lz100 mentioned. The choice is yours.

Comment: it is still not working properly, when you are still editing the input the warning keeps generating ! in your solution, it is not prevent it from rendering, but keeps generating the warning while you are editing the input ! let say you put `111` as input and you get the warning. you click the backspace to change the input to `1`, still after removing one character, you get another warning !